# Couchbase group by data

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I know the couchbase map/reduce can be used to group by using group_level but I want group the data and not just want the count.Here is the scenario

Here is the data in couchbase

`{"key":"key1","value":"value1"}
 {"key":"key2","value":"value2"}
 {"key":"key1","value":"value3"}`

Now I want, is

`{key:"key1","value":[value1,value3]}
{key:"key2","value":value2}`

Is there a way I can achieve this thru map/reduce functionality in couchbase?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I was able to. The provided solution by Laurent helped.In reduce method, You can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. The compound key documentation might help you: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/compound-keys.html